# Can't save image as .png

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I am working on a program I wrote last year. It worked fine then, but now I am getting an error when I run it. I am a beginner in Python and am not sure how to resolve this. Essentially, I get the following error when I try to save as .png.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

# Use PIL to import image
img = Image.open("jenny.jpg")
newImg=img.save("jenny.png")
```

ValueError: unknown file extension: .png

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `Pillow` instead of `PIL`

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("jenny.jpg")
newImg=img.save("jenny.png")
```

Comment: It should work. Please tell me when you try. @user9785589

Comment: @Omer Tekbiyik: You can get pillow from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Comment: It absolutely works. Thanks again. How do I resolve this question?